# Django-admin expand the graphical inputField for CharField variable

Tags: django-forms, django-admin

I have a CharField of 400 chars in my model but in the admin built-in form the inputfield is too small. How can I expand the input field in the admin pages?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `formfield_overrides` to expand your input field:
(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides)

So, something like this in `admin.py`:

```
from django.forms import TextInput, Textarea
from django.db import models

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        ...
    }
```